# slideToggle on second submenu

Tags: jquery, html

I followed this tut:

http://www.falconmasters.com/web-design/menu-desplegable-adaptable-dispositivos-moviles/

added an submenu inside the submenu, and added an event.stopPropagation to my Jquery.

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main() {
    $('.menu_bar').click(function() {
        if (contador == 1) {
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '0'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        }
    });

    $('.submenu').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

My problem is that its toggles fine when smaller than 800px, but higher than 800px the second submenu it not responding at all.

Hope you can help me

Here is the HTML

```
<header>
<div class="contentWrapper">

    <div class="menu_bar">
    <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-list2">      </span>Menú</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="level-1">
            <!--Parent #1-->
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>

            <!--Parent #2-->
            <li>
                <a href="#">Agenda</a>
            </li>

            <!--Parent #3-->
            <li>
                <a href="#">Nieuws</a>
            </li>

            <!--Parent #4-->
            <li class="submenu">

                <a href="#">Foto's</a>

                <ul class="children">

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Chaffee</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Scoutcar</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Brencarrier</a> 
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Halftrack</a>   
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Hummer</a>  
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dodge</a>   
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">T34</a> 
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Mig17</a>   
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Willeys</a> 
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Harley</a>  
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Eng. Bikes</a>  
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">SD-KZF 251</a>  
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Greyhound</a>   
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Ferret</a>  
                    </li>

                    <li class="submenu">
                        <a href="#">Museum 40-45</a>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #4</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </li>

                    <li class="submenu">
                        <a href="#">Mariniers</a>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #4</a></li>

                        </ul>   
                    </li>

                    <li class="submenu">
                        <a href="#">Optochten</a>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grandchild #4</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>

            <!--Parent #5-->
            <li>
                <a href="#">Films/tv</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Links</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Gastenboek</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

and here is the sass.

```
.menu_bar
  display: none

header
  width: 100%
  nav
    background: #023859
    z-index: 1000
    max-width: 100%
    width: 95%
    margin: 20px auto
    ul
      list-style: none
      li
        display: inline-block
        position: relative
        &:hover
          background: #E6344A
        a
          color: #fff
          display: block
          text-decoration: none
          padding: 10px
          span
            margin-right: 10px
        &:hover .children
          display: block
        .children
          display: none
          background: #011826
          position: absolute
          width: 250%
          z-index: 1000
          padding-left: 0px
          li
            display: block
            overflow: hidden
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
            a
              display: block
              span
                float: right
                position: relative
                top: 3px
                margin-right: 0
                margin-left: 10px
        .caret
          position: relative
          top: 3px
          margin-left: 10px
          margin-right: 0px

@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
  body
    padding-top: 80px
  .menu_bar
    display: block
    width: 100%
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    background: #E6344A
    .bt-menu
      display: block
      padding: 20px
      color: #fff
      overflow: hidden
      font-size: 25px
      font-weight: bold
      text-decoration: none
    span
      float: right
      font-size: 40px
  header nav
    width: 80%
    height: calc(100% - 80px)
    position: fixed
    right: 100%
    margin: 0
    overflow: scroll
    .level-1
      margin-left: 2px
      padding-left: 0px
    ul li
      display: block
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
      a
        display: block
      &:hover .children
        display: none
      .children
        width: 100%
        position: relative
        li a
          margin-left: 5px
      .caret
        float: right
```

Comment: can you post your html? or better yet, recreate this issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Actually we're going to need your CSS too since thats most likely where the issue is

Comment: Indenting your code [really isn't difficult](http://www.jspretty.com/), but reading un-indented code *is.* (I've indented the JS is this question, but next time please help us to help you...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**NOTE** I converted your sass to css, you can use an online converter like [this one](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) to switch it back) There are two issues: the first is `overflow:hidden` being called on:

```
header nav ul li .children li {
   display: block;
   /*overflow: hidden;*/ //remove
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Which is preventing the grandchild nav from showing since it's set to `position: absolute` thus flowing outside of its parent. Once you fix that there will be another issue, which is the grandchild subnav being shown already before clicking. That's because styles are being inherited from the parent (both class names are `.children`). On `:hover` you need to set `.children`'s `ul` to `display: none`. (and if you want it to display off to the side, you can add a `left` and `top` property as well):

```
header nav ul li:hover .children ul {
   display: none; 
   top: 0; //optional
   left: 100%; //optional
}
```

Now the grandchild submenu will toggle on click

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zv617ggx/2/)

Comment: This was indeed what i was looking for, only problem now is that in the state of less than 800px, the complete submenu is hovered(in this case red)

Comment: @WimHuiskes from the code this appears to be intentional. What do you prefer to happen? You could always add a menu button that the user can click on

Comment: I Dont know if i understand you completely, but what i want is every LI is hovered seperately, when the screensize is less than 800px, the second submenu hovers the UL, instead of the LI

Comment: @WimHuiskes I think I understand, you just need to reset `left: 100%` on `header nav ul li:hover .children ul` to `left: 0` in your media query

Comment: @WimHuiskes I forgot to mention I updated my fiddle with my last comment

Comment: iwant to thank you very much, i have spent about 20 hours on this problem, and you solved it in a couple of minutes. I am glad i found this site. Thank you and the stack overflow community.

Comment: @WimHuiskes no problem. Glad to help. Can you do me a favor and check this off as resolved?